# Prolog: An example for checking a list for certain keywords?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to test whether a list contains particular keywords.

Example (Java):

```
if (list.contains(keywordA) || list.contains(keywordB) || list.contains(keywordC))
```

I have tried variants of the following with no luck.

Variant A:
    ( member(X, List), (X='boyfriend'; X='girlfriend') ->
            writeln('Lets talk about your relationships.')
          ;
            writeln('Not again!')
    )

Variant B:

```
( member(['boyfriend', 'girlfriend'], List)
```

`returns false, on input ['boyfriend','issues']`

Comment: Please tell us what the input to this was, and the expected/actual output. "Not working" is too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write it like so:

```
test(List) :- 
    (member(boyfriend, List) ; member(girlfriend, List)) 
        -> writeln('Let''s talk about your relationships.') 
        ;  writeln('Not again!').
```

This appears to work:

```
?- test([something,to,do,with,my,boyfriend,mmkay,'?']).
Let's talk about your relationships.
true.

?- test([something,to,do,with,my,friend,mmkay,'?']).
Not again!
true.
```

Without knowing the rest of your code, the input you gave, the output you got, and what you were expecting it's very hard to assist.

By the way, you don't need to quote lowercase atoms.